# For loop wont run properly

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to build a function that changes values in innerHTML of elements which have one class name, but different number values.

as in:

```
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">5</div>
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">300</div>
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">250</div>
```

And I want a calculation (same for all) to run through all of them and then change the innerHTML of each to the result of each.

as in:

```
calcuation = 5 * innerHTML;
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">25</div>
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">1500</div>
<div class="ingredient-assignment__quantity">1250</div>
```

My JS function looks like this:

```
function ingredientChange (){


 var portionsBefore = document.getElementById('portions');
  var ingredients = document.getElementsByClassName('ingredient-assignment__quantity');

  function getPortions(event) {
    const getID = event.target.id;
    if (getID == "minus") {
      var y = Number(portionsBefore.innerHTML) - 1;
    }
    else {
      var y = Number(portionsBefore.innerHTML) + 1;
    }

    changeIngredients(y);
    portionsBefore.innerHTML = y;
  }

  function changeIngredients(y) {    
    var arr = Object.keys(ingredients).map((k) => ingredients[k])
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
      var changeValues = Number(arr[i].innerHTML) / Number(portionsBefore.innerHTML);
      var changedValues = Number(changeValues) * y;
    }
  }

  function addEventListeners () {
    document.getElementById('minus').addEventListener('click', getPortions, false);
    document.getElementById('plus').addEventListener('click', getPortions, false);
  }
  addEventListeners();
}

ingredientChange();
```

And everything except for the `for` loop works fine.

I cant find, whats wrong with the `for` loop

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `for` loop

`arr.lenght` should be `arr.length`.

Comment: @Jousi, no problem. It can happen. By the way, you should see `No such property` type of error on the console.